# How do I correctly use the date_select model object helper? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, calendar, date

I'm trying to design a form that lets the user set the date at which they will go shopping. This form will create a "List" model and define the "date" attribute. I created this list model with:

```
$ rails generate model List name:string date:date user_id:integer
```

Right now I only want my form to set the date. Here's my code:

```
<%= form_for @list do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But when I submit the form in my browser, the page tells me that the date field is still blank, even though I submitted the form with a date selected (I've set my list object to validate the presence of the "date" attribute). Why does the form fail to successfully submit the date and create the list? Thanks!

```
1 error prohibited this list from being saved:

There were problems with the following fields:

    * Date can't be blank
```

Here's my controller code:

```
ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @list  = current_user.lists.build(params[:list])
    if @list.save
      flash[:success] = "Shopping List created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the date is being passed in params to #create?  You can do this be debugging params hash in your application template (Google it).  Include controller code for both #new and #create please.

Comment: I've posted the #create controller code above. Don't have one for #new. Checking to see if data is passed to create.

Comment: Got it! Turns out I had just forgotten to make the date attribute accessible within the list model. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest 2 things:

1) Don't call the field 'date'.  It's a reserved word, and may give conflicts.

2) Use a plugin like calendar_date_select ( https://github.com/timcharper/calendar_date_select ).  Your users will love it.

Comment: or consider dropping in a JQuery UI date/time picker (there's one by Trent Richardson iirc, that does both)...